# Compute new records based on existing ones (e.g., sum of 2 records)?

Tags: postgresql

**Background**
I have an inventory where I register the number of fruits I have in stock — both expected and actual quantities.

For some fruits (e.g., here Banana and Cherry), I might not have both records.

My table looks then like this:

```
| Fruit  | RecordType | Qty |
|--------|------------|----:|
| Apple  | Expected   |  13 |
| Apple  | Actual     |  17 |
| Banana | Actual     |   8 |
| Cherry | Expected   |  42 |
| Durian | Actual     |   0 |
| Durian | Expected   |   1 |
```

This table gets partially updated over time (i.e. I might only change the `Apple | Actual` quantity, or add the `Banana | Expected` record).

**Question**
➥ Is it possible to automatically compute new records based on the existing ones? If yes, how?

In our example, I might want to compute the `Variation` between the actual and the expected value: i.e. add the `{fruit} | Variation | [{fruit | Actual}(Qty) − {fruit | Expected}(Qty)]` record when I have both `Actual` and `Expected` records for a given `{fruit}`.

In our case, I'd like that my table becomes this:

```
| Fruit  | RecordType | Qty |
|--------|------------|----:|
| Apple  | Expected   |  13 |
| Apple  | Actual     |  17 |
| Banana | Actual     |   8 |
| Cherry | Expected   |  42 |
| Durian | Actual     |   0 |
| Durian | Expected   |   1 |
| Apple  | Variation  |   4 | ← newly computed record
| Durian | Variation  |  -1 | ← newly computed record
```

You can see that there is no `Variation` record for `Banana` or `Cherry`, because they are missing their `Expected` or `Actual` record, respectively.

Comment: Maybe this is just because you simplified your question to the point that it no longer reflects the actual problem very well, but wouldn't it make a lot more sense to have "actual_qty" and "expected_qty" be separate columns rather than separate rows?

Comment: @jjanes Indeed, you are right. The thing is that I have "Quantity" as column, but also "Height", "Width", etc. So duplicating all these columns is indeed an option, yet one I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the design, but sometimes we just have to deal with the what we find even if we don't like it.  Here is a query that gets you the 'Variation' part you are looking for:

```
select fruit, 'Variation' as recordtype, act_qty-exp_qty as qty from
   (select fruit, qty as exp_qty from foobar where recordtype ='Expected') as ex 
join 
   (select fruit,qty as act_qty from foobar where recordtype='Actual') as ac 
using (fruit);
```

You can either insert those results into the table (after clearing out the old results) or you can create a view with UNION ALL so that the Variation rows appear in the view, without ever physically existing.